# How to Fix Cannot resolve keyword 'date_added' into field?

Tags: python, django, heroku

the BUG :

Cannot resolve keyword 'date_added' into field. Choices are: date, entry, id, owner, owner_id, text

here s My Models :

```
    from `django`.db import models
    from `django.contrib.auth`.models import User

class Topic(models.Model) :

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model) :

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

`heres` My Views functions

```
def topics(request) :
        topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).`order_by`('date_added')
        context = {'topics':topics}
        return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Comment: `date_added` isn't a field on your model, but `date` is - either add the field or change the name in your `order_by()` function

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "date_added" field to your Topic model, because order_by orders items in Topic model, but now you have only Date field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).